# Some doubts regarding decidable sets

Tags: logic, algorithms

I've been working at one of the problems, related to the decidability.

Let's denote $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as a  computable increasing function, $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ is  a decidable set. How to prove that the $f(A)$ is also decidable?

My attempts: 
1) First of all, if $A$ is decidable, then  there is an indicator function such that $1_{A}(x)$ is equal to $1$ or $0$, depending on the element $x$.
2) How to establish, if $f(x_{0})$ belongs to $f(A)$ or not? Exactly, we know if $x_{0} \in A$ or not, so it's easy to establish if $ f(x_{0}) \in f(A)$ or not.

The main idea seems to be obvious (or not?), anyway, how does the condition of the function's increase influence on the possible way of solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Informally, to find out whether $b\in f(A)$, compute $f(1)$, $f(2)$, and so on, testing for each $k$ membership in $A$ until we either hit $b$ or get past $b$ without hitting it. That gives an algorithm for testing membership in $f(A)$.